# How to insert text to a database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Input string from text area

```
line1
line2 ‘
”line3″
<div>line4<div>
```

Wanted in database

```
line<br />1line2 '<br />"line3"<br />&lt;div&gt;line4&lt;div&gt;
```

I'm using this but it has some error. Nothing inserted to database from example i gave, when an input has a quotes.

```
$input = $_POST['textarea'];
$input = trim($input);
$input = htmlspecialchars($input);
$input = nl2br($input);
$input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
```

Comment: nothing inserted to database from example i gave. when an input has a quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Better way will be not use nl2br when you save into DB. 
Will be much better use nl2br when you will print textarea value on the page

```
echo nl2br($dataFromDB);
```

Comment: the same is true for `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that the error is caused by the **type of your column in the data base** !!!
Is it type of **text** or **varchar** ???

Generally, try to get the data type as specific as you can. If your strings will never exceed some upper limit of characters, then go with **VARCHAR** because it will be a little more efficient. If you need more space, go with **TEXT**. If you aren't sure how much space your text will take up, you should probably go with **TEXT**; the performance difference isn't very large, and it's better to be future-proof than risk having to change it later when your requirements change.

**VARCHAR** you can set a limit for how many chars it will accept per record, **text** is (virtually) unlimited..

**MySQL** will internally **convert** TEXT to varchar while creating temporary tables. So it is better to use VARCHAR if possible.

It really depends on your **data type**.

If your field is **fixed-length** (e.g. a 32-character hash value), then use **CHAR**. This has better performance because every entry takes up the same space per row.

The standard limit for **VARCHAR** was 255 characters but I think it's been increased now. TEXT is pretty damn long and is generally only used for **big content** like a whole blog post, and comments if you don't want a limit.

With regard to size there is no (or very little) difference between **VARCHAR** and **TEXT** since they just store what they need to. **CHAR** fields will always take up their allotted length.

I hope it will help you, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PHP` fuctions

`string urlencode ( string $str )` to encode the text and then insert into database

`$input = urlencode ($input);`

and `string urldecode ( string $str )` to decode the text

`$input = urldecode ($input);`

[try online fuction here](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/urlencode/)